# Why does trash show some files even when there is nothing in it?

Tags: trash

Why does trash show some files even when there is nothing inside the trash?

Comment: Maybe it would help to provide some more information.

Comment: Might just be a bug where it does not refresh the applet.

Comment: I empty the trash, when I keep the mouse pointer on the trash it shows "6 items in trash", but nothing is inside the folder. I even tried to see the hidden files, no hidden files too.

Comment: I have had this happen several times. It seems to have something to do with removable drives. If you put in a USB drive or flash drive and delete a bunch of files then unmount the drive, the trash can will show that it has files. If you put the drive back in and then empty the trash, and unmount the drive, the trash can will show empty. I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but it can be annoying if you don't remember which drive you deleted the files from.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking as root:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

What is in the Trash folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same after my disk was completely full. I emptied the trash afterwards, but even after reboot I still got the summary telling me about remaining files in the trash.

You should be able to get rid of that stuff by running

`rm -rf ~/.Trash/*`

(maybe with "sudo"). As far as I know the technical background is that the trash contains a summary file `.trashinfo`, which can get out of sync with the real content on disk.

Comment: http://linux.bigresource.com/Ubuntu-Security-Secure-Empty-Trash-bin-Gfr1MvBuH.html#0JPr0EDqo

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there are hidden files in the trash. Toggle the hidden file visibility with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.